# cypress testing of mendix app - unable to find mxui.js, theme.compiled.css files

Tags: cypress, mendix

I am trying to test a mendix app with cypress.

On trying to load the index file, I get the following in both the mendix and cypress logs.
404 - file not found for file: index.html/theme.compiled.css
404 - file not found for file: index.html/mxclientsystem/mxui/mxui.js

Which makes sense as it would be very unlikely that there are files under an html file in a directory structure.

Looking at the source code in the browser

```html
 <script src="mxclientsystem/mxui/mxui.js?637896725776724820"></script>
```

Why would cypress be searching for mxui.js under index.html?

Is this a problem with mendix? With cypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress works with a served web page.

Not sure how a mendix app works, but if I want to test an `index.html` that has scripts and css resources to load, I would use VSCode "Open with live server" option on the index.

This will give me a URL usually localhost:5500 to visit in the app.

If there's any transforms required (e.g is CSS is in SASS format), you would need something more sophisticated involving Webpack and Babel.

Bottom line, serve your app in dev mode and use

```
cy.visit('url-as-used-in-browser')
```

to give Cypress access to the compiled page.

---

I see from the `mendix` tag

> Mendix is a app platform-as-a-service (aPaaS) for Rapid Application Development. The rapid aPaaS offering prioritizes speed and agility and utilizes a “no code” principle

So, there's no code to serve. Just use the `cy.visit(url)` command using the same URL a user would access.

Comment: Hi Fody,
thanks for taking the time to reply.
Yes, the first command in my script has always been visit() and that works. But it never finds anything in the page (get() or contains()) because cypress can't find mxui.js. And that is because it's looking under index.html, which is not a folder.

When I access the app outside of cypress in the browser, then I can see the network requests for mxui.js at http://localhost:8080/mxclientsystem/mxui/mxui.js.
But for some reason, cypress is looking under http://localhost:8080/index.html/mxclientsystem/mxui/mxui.js

Comment: So the specific command is `cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')`?

Comment: And do you have a `baseUrl` configured?

Comment: Yes I had configured baseurl but I just realised that I had configured it incorrectly which (surprise, surprise) caused problems.
Onwards and upwards (!).